# Form validation with Javascript: Error label not set

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create an html form.
I was filling up and validating the form with javascript. I also created an error label for each field.
To do this, I created an object `form_fields` that contains the field name, as well as the input element, error element, and the corresponding validate function.
The `input_field` and `error_field` of each field is set while filling the form.
My code:

```js
const form_fields = {
    name : { validate: validate_name },
    roll : { validate: validate_roll }
};

const form = document.getElementById("student_data");
function fill_form() {
    for(const [field, data] of Object.entries(form_fields)) {
        form.innerHTML += `
        <label for="${field}_field">Enter your ${field}: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="${field}_field" name="${field}_field">
        <label style="color: red;" id="${field}_error_label">*</label><br>
        `;
        data.input_field = document.getElementById(field + "_field");
        data.error_field = document.getElementById(field + "_error_label");
        console.log(field, data.input_field, data.error_field);
    }
    form.innerHTML += '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
}

function validate_name(name, error_field) {
    console.log(name);
    if(name == "") {
        error_field.innerHTML = "Name is required.";
        return true;
    }
}

function validate_roll(roll, error_field) {
    if(roll == "") {
        error_field.innerHTML = "Roll number is required.";
        return true;
    }
    else if(! new RegExp("^19HCS40[0-9]{2}$").test(roll)) {
        error_field.innerHTML = "Provided roll number is not correct.";
        return true;
    }
}

function validate() {
    let error_occurred = false;

    console.log(form_fields.roll.error_field);
    error_occurred = validate_roll('', form_fields.roll.error_field);
    console.log(error_occurred);

    return false;//!error_occurred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Some Task</title>
</head>
<body onload="fill_form()">
    <form id="student_data" onsubmit="return validate()"></form>
    <!--<script src="validate.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran the line `error_occurred = validate_roll('', form_fields.roll.error_field);`, I expected it would set the error label and return `true`.
But, for some reason, the label is not set, even though the `validate_roll` function returns `true`.
An even more interesting thing was that the console was saying the error was set!

```
name <input type=​"text" id=​"name_field" name=​"name_field">​ <label style=​"color:​ red;​" id=​"name_error_label">​*​</label>​ validate.js:15 
roll <input type=​"text" id=​"roll_field" name=​"roll_field">​ <label style=​"color:​ red;​" id=​"roll_error_label">​*​</label> validate.js:43 
<label style=​"color:​ red;​" id=​"roll_error_label">​Roll number is required.​</label>​                                     validate.js:45 
true
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the way you construct your form. When you do `form.innerHTML += …` you don't add code, you overwrite the whole code. As a result, when your form is completed, the elements stored in `input_field` and `error_field` of the `form_fields` object are not the same as the ones in your form final code.

One way to fix that, is to assign `input_field` and `error_field` properties after the form as heen created (see the snippet below).

Another option would be to remove `input_field` and `error_field` as well as the second parameter of `validate_*` function and get the element by id inside the respective function.

```js
const form_fields = {
  name: {
    validate: validate_name
  },
  roll: {
    validate: validate_roll
  }
};

const form = document.getElementById("student_data");

function fill_form() {
  for (const [field, data] of Object.entries(form_fields)) {
    form.innerHTML += `
        <label for="${field}_field">Enter your ${field}: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="${field}_field" name="${field}_field">
        <label style="color: red;" id="${field}_error_label">*</label><br>
        `;
  }
  form.innerHTML += '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
  
  for (const [field, data] of Object.entries(form_fields)) {
    data.input_field = document.getElementById(field + "_field");
    data.error_field = document.getElementById(field + "_error_label");
    console.log(field, data.input_field, data.error_field);
  }
}

function validate_name(name, error_field) {
  console.log(name);
  if (name == "") {
    error_field.innerHTML = "Name is required.";
    return true;
  }
}

function validate_roll(roll, error_field) {
  if (roll == "") {
    error_field.innerHTML = "Roll number is required.";
    return true;
  } else if (!new RegExp("^19HCS40[0-9]{2}$").test(roll)) {
    error_field.innerHTML = "Provided roll number is not correct.";
    return true;
  }
}

function validate() {

    // this way all the validate_* function are executed  
  const error_occurred = [
      validate_roll('', form_fields.roll.error_field),
      validate_name('', form_fields.name.error_field)
  ].some(error => error);
  
  console.log(error_occurred);

  return false; //!error_occurred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Some Task</title>
</head>
<body onload="fill_form()">
    <form id="student_data" onsubmit="return validate()"></form>
    <!--<script src="validate.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But, even when I put valid input, the error labels are set to `Name is required` and `Roll number is required.`

Comment: Did you change the `validate_*` functions ? So far you're calling `validate_roll('', form_fields.roll.error_field),` which means whatever is in the input you always call the function with `''` (an empty string) hence the error message. Try instead `validate_roll(form_fields.roll.input_field.value, form_fields.roll.error_field)` and, of course same goes for `validate_name`